# Karate API : File not found exception while calling a feature file from other folder

Tags: karate

Getting file not found error if calling feature file is present other package
Test.feature is in Folder1 and I am this in another feature file from Folder2
like below

```
    * def res = call read('Test.feature')
```

Getting error

```
   - javascript evaluation failed: read('Test.feature')
```

If I place Test.feature file in Folder2 and run it works fine.

Even I tried callonce with classpath like below but still getting the same error file not found.

```
   * def res= call read('classpath:Test.feature')
```

Using latest version of karate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you never used relative paths before?

```
* def res = call read('../Folder1/Test.feature')
```

But even using `classpath`, you managed to forget to indicate the folder in which it is present :

```
* def res = call read('classpath:Folder1/Test.feature')
```